# How to check if the element has certain style and if it has style change the style of another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Help me realize something like this:

I have two menus http://osiyo-nur.uz/osiyo-nur.uz/test6/ one of them is invisible and when i hover at one of them the second menu getting visible and the background is getting overlay effect.
In this case im using buttons instead of menus. I used the condition but it doesn't work. It would be good if you'll help me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(".none").css('display') == 'block') {
    $("#overlay").css('display', 'block');
  } else {
    $("#overlay").css('display', 'none');
  }

});
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
  width: 60%;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.block:hover+.none {
  display: block;
}

.block:hover .overlay {
  display: block;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GoodGross</title>

  <link href="css\style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <!-- HEADER PART STARTS -->
    <div class="main_content">
      <div class="test">
        <a class="btn btn-danger block">Block</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger none">None</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" id="overlay"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So what is the issue exactly?

Comment: I want to do the overlay effect if the second button appears and if it dissappears overlay effect must be dissappeared too

Comment: Well that javascript code only runs when the page loads, it does not keep on running.... So either you need to add mouseevents or just fix the CSS so it shows it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.block').hover(function(){
        $('.overlay').css('display', 'block');
        $('.none').css('display', 'block');
    });
    $('.none').hover(function(){
        $('.overlay').css('display', 'none');
        $('.none').css('display', 'none');
    });

});
```

And need to add additional css into your css file

```
/*aditional Css*/
.none{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using this

```
$('.block').on('mouseover', function() {
$("#overlay").css('display', 'block');
});

$('.block').on('mouseleave', function() {
$("#overlay").css('display', 'none');
});
```

```js
$('.block').on('mouseover', function() {
$("#overlay").css('display', 'block');
});

$('.block').on('mouseleave', function() {
$("#overlay").css('display', 'none');
});
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
  width: 60%;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.block:hover+.none {
  display: block;
}

.block:hover .overlay {
  display: block;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GoodGross</title>

  <link href="css\style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <!-- HEADER PART STARTS -->
    <div class="main_content">
      <div class="test">
        <a class="btn btn-danger block">Block</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger none">None</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" id="overlay"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery hover() method 
    $(document).ready(function() {

```
  $("a.block").hover(function() {
    $("#overlay").css('display', 'block');
  }, function() {
    $("#overlay").css('display', 'none');
  });

});
```

see demo on this url : https://jsfiddle.net/jitenderdhankhar/85qq5Lwo

Comment: i tried with hover method but it's bugging when  i move cursor every time

Comment: Issue was with z-index of overlay class. I have updated the jsfiddle.